# jxls 2.5 compacibility for using jxls-poi-1.0.12

Tags: gradle, apache-poi, jxls

I am using jxls-poi-1.0.12.
After jxls 2.5 release, gradle auto updated the jxls to 2.5. For the result I got an exception when running JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(context, transformer)

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.adjustTableSize(Lorg/jxls/common/CellRef;Lorg/jxls/common/Size;)V
at org.jxls.command.EachCommand.applyAt(EachCommand.java:262)
at org.jxls.area.XlsArea.applyAt(XlsArea.java:172)
at org.jxls.command.EachCommand.processCollection(EachCommand.java:296)
at org.jxls.command.EachCommand.applyAt(EachCommand.java:255)
at org.jxls.area.XlsArea.applyAt(XlsArea.java:172)
```

I checked jxls 2.5 update. I find when EachCommand running, jxls 2.5 added adjustTableSize() method to transformer interface. However, PoiTransformer has not implement this method so I got this error. That means jxls 2.5 don't have compacibility for jxls-poi-1.0.12.

Of cause, I can upgrade my poi but it takes many time. Is that possible to downgrade my jxls or disable to run Transformer.adjustTableSize()?

Here is my build.gradle

```
compile group: 'org.jxls', name: 'jxls-jexcel', version: '1.0.6'
compile group: 'org.jxls', name: 'jxls-poi', version: '1.0.12'
compile group: 'org.jxls', name:'jxls', version :'2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had encountered same issue today.
After investigation, we found the way to solve it. so please let me share.

please try to change the gradle.build as below.

```
compile ("org.jxls:jxls-poi:1.0.12"){
    transitive = false
  }
```

once you change, gradle will ignore the dependencies which jxls-poi specifying.

please see the document in detail. (this document is for gradle 4.10, but we tested gradle 3.x)
https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html#sub:disabling_resolution_transitive_dependencies

---

this is because jxls-poi's version setting. here is the specification of POI's Dependency Version Requirement Specification.

- 1.0: "Soft" requirement on 1.0 (just a recommendation, if it matches all other - - - ranges for the dependency)
- [1.0]: "Hard" requirement on 1.0
- (,1.0]: x <= 1.0
- [1.2,1.3]: 1.2 <= x <= 1.3
- [1.0,2.0): 1.0 <= x < 2.0
- **[1.5,): x >= 1.5**
- (,1.0],[1.2,): x <= 1.0 or x >= 1.2; multiple sets are comma-separated
- (,1.1),(1.1,): this excludes 1.1 (for example if it is known not to work in -combination with this library)

https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification

so, `org.jxls:jxls:[2.4.0,)` means use 2.4.0 or later.

```
# this is the part of result of gradle dependencies command.
...
+--- org.jxls:jxls-poi:1.0.12
|    |    +--- org.jxls:jxls:[2.4.0,) -> 2.5.0 (*)
...
```

once you exclude jxls-poi's setting, jxls's version will be changed to the specified version.

before

```
|    +--- org.jxls:jxls:2.4.0 -> 2.5.0 (*)
```

after(solved)

```
|    +--- org.jxls:jxls:2.4.0 (*)
```

Comment: It's work!! But I tried yesterday too. I think maybe system cache. But anyway thank you for let me try again to success. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use Jxls 2.5.0 with Apache POI you have to switch to `jxls-poi` `1.1.0` which has the Transformer.adjustTableSize() implemented.

If you do not want to use the latest POI version you can try to exclude it from jxls-poi dependencies and use an older POI version however this may not work if there were breaking API changes between the POI releases.

**Update 16.02.2019:**
Jxls 2.5.1 version is now released. 
This version should be backwards compatible with the jxls-poi `1.0.x` versions so the issue should be gone when the version becomes available in Maven Central.

Comment: Yes I want to use `jxls-poi` `1.0.12` but gradle auto updated my `jslx` to `2.5.0`.

Answer (score 1):

What has been said above makes sense, but it is not quite right

```
compile("org.jxls:jxls-poi:1.0.15"){
        transitive = false
    }
compile("org.jxls:jxls:2.4.0")
```